# Speed Up API Requests & Overall Python Code

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, api

I'm not asking for help solving a problem but rather asking for help for possible ways to improve the speed of my program.

**Essentially what this does is:**
Tracks market data by pulling the data from the public API provided by the devs.
Compares the data with a pre-determined price I input, if its a good deal it does a POST request directly into the blockchain using the public API provided by the blockchain.

I'm competing with a fair bunch of other programs that do the same and sometimes I win, sometimes I lose and I wanna improve my winning chances by optimizing my code as much as possible.
PS: Everything here is 100% legal and allowed, both APIs are public and given to us by the devs.

I start the threads this way: (I have multiple and each needs different variables)

```
    collection = 'xxxx'
    template = 154041
    price = 1
    x1 = threading.Thread(target=self.check2, args=(collection,template,price,))
    x1.start()

    
    collection = 'yyyyy'
    schema = 'yyyyy'
    price = 2
    x2 = threading.Thread(target=self.maxspeed, args=(collection,schema,price,))
    x2.start()
```

Essentially it starts function "check2" and "maxspeed" on different thread, they're essentially the same function just different endpoints of the REST API & different variables.

Then what it does is: (I get the info directly from the block chain right at the start because It's needed for the POST request at the end, I can use the same info for ~5-7 hours, hence why I use time.time() to track time elapsed since the last time I grabbed the info so that after 5 hours has passed, the loop will grab the info again instead of having to grab it every time before each POST request)
I also use these requests at the start to load up the pool_connections(idk if this is how you use them) but essentially to make the requests faster.

```
def check2(self,collection,template,price):
    start = time.time()
    URL = f"https://xxxxxxx.com"
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=3))
    headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/605.1.15"}
    s.headers.update(headers)
    test = s.get('https://get info from the blockchain url.com').json()
    ref_block_num, ref_block_prefix = get_tapos_info(test['last_irreversible_block_id'])
    chain_id = test['chain_id']
    test2 = s.get('https://POST Transaction url.com')
    stopsale = 0
    while 1:
#### This is the if check to see if 5 hours have gone by so I get the renewed blockchain data
        if (((time.time() - start) / 60) / 60) > 5:
            test = s.get('https://xxxxxx').json()
            ref_block_num, ref_block_prefix = get_tapos_info(test['last_irreversible_block_id'])
            chain_id = test['chain_id']
            start = time.time()
            print('resetting time / blockchain data')
        try:
            resp = s.get(URL).json()
        except:
            print(f'error in try with {collection} {template}')

        try:
            listing_price = resp['data'][0]['price']['amount']
            sale_id = int(resp['data'][0]['sale_id'])
        except:
            print(f'error in {collection} {template}')
            continue
        if int(listing_price) <= int(price):
            if stopsale != sale_id: ### This if is to prevent spamming POST's for the same sale_id 
### Now starts the Buying part, it will do a bunch of stuff with datastreams that even I don't fully understand myself but apparently it's needed for the blockchain.

                price2 = formatprice(listing_price,8) ### this is a small function I wrote to properly format the price because the price given by the API is kinda weirdly formatted, hard to explain

                tx = {Payload goes here}


                data = tx['actions'][0]['data']
                ds = DataStream()
                ds.pack_name(data['from'])
                ds.pack_name(data['to'])
                ds.pack_asset(data['quantity'])
                ds.pack_string(data['memo'])


                data1 = tx['actions'][1]['data']
                ds2 = DataStream()
                ds2.pack_name(data1['buyer'])
                ds2.pack_uint64(data1['sale_id'])
                ds2.pack_uint64(data1['intended_delphi_median'])
                ds2.pack_name(data1['taker_marketplace'])


                tx['actions'][0]['data'] = binascii.hexlify(ds.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
                tx['actions'][1]['data'] = binascii.hexlify(ds2.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')

                tx.update({
                "expiration": get_expiration(datetime.utcnow(), timedelta(minutes=15).total_seconds()),
                "ref_block_num": ref_block_num,
                "ref_block_prefix": ref_block_prefix,
                "max_net_usage_words": 0,
                "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
                "delay_sec": 0,
                "context_free_actions": [],
                "transaction_extensions": [],
                "context_free_data": []
                })

                auth = tx['actions'][0]['authorization'][0]
                private_key = "xxxxxxx"

                tx_id, tx = sign_tx(
                   chain_id,
                   tx,
                   private_key,
                )

                ds = DataStream()
                ds.pack_transaction(tx)
                packed_trx = binascii.hexlify(ds.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
                tx = build_push_transaction_body(tx['signatures'][0], packed_trx)
                res = s.post('https://POST TRANSACTION.com', json=tx)
                result = res.json()
                print(result)
                try:
                    sqlite_insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO bought (saleid, price) VALUES ('{sale_id}','{price2}')"""
                    cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_query)
                    dblist.commit()
                except:
                    print('error inserting into db lul')
                print('sale ID:')
                print(sale_id)
                print(price2)
                stopsale = sale_id
```

Is there anything you guys would modify to improve the speed?
I'm still getting outpaced by some other people occasionally.

I also live very close to the API hosting actually so that's a bonus I have over others already.

Comment: Is the slowest part `resp = s.get(URL).json()`? If so, does `URL` have any options to perhaps reduce the response payload?

Comment: the slowest part is the request yea, I changed and now I'm using orjson instead of default python .json() parser which improved runtime by 0,3 every 5 loops which is significant but I also wanted to use pycurl instead of requests as it's a lot faster but having a hard time getting it to work. And nope, payload has to be the way it is :l